# Quadratic Formula Calculator Python

Tags: python

What is wrong with the program below?

```
#Quadratic Formula Calculator
#Asks the user for a, b, and c

a = int(input("Enter a: "))
b = int(input("Enter b: "))
c = int(input("Enter c: "))

d = b**2-4*a*c

#Program output should be in the exact format below:

#Enter a:

#Enter b:

#Enter c:

#The answers are x=3.0 and x=-2.0

#!!!!!!!!

#Put a \n at the end of your input string to the 

#quotation marks-> input("Enter a: \n")

#!!!!!!!!

if d < 0:
    print ("This equation has no real solution")
elif d == 0:
    x = (-b+math.sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))/2*a
    print ("This equation has one solutions: "), x
else:
    x1 = (-b+math.sqrt((b**2)-(4*(a*c))))/(2*a)
    x2 = (-b-math.sqrt((b**2)-(4*(a*c))))/(2*a)
    print ("This equation has two solutions: ", x1, " or", x2)
    math =
```

Comment: ```math = ``` is wrong. ```math``` is a module. And.... You have not imported the ```math``` module

Comment: Also, you need to check for a == 0

Answer (score 0):

You have a line that's simply `math =`, and `import math` is not shown in your code, also when d=0 you forgot to add parenthesis.

Comment: im dumb, how did i not see that

Comment: how do you think i should fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First things first.
You are **using the `math` module but you haven't *imported* it**
So `import math` at the top of the code.

The `,x` is outside the `print` statement

```
print ("This equation has one solutions: ",x)
```

Even if you import `math`, `math =`  will surely over ride it. Also, there is no assignment to it.

Here `d` is already defined.

```
d = b**2-4*a*c
```

No need to do:

```
(-b+math.sqrt((b**2)-(4*(a*c))))/(2*a)
```

You can do:

```
(-b+math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
```